# Does glob work differently with [[ ]] vs [ ] in Bash?

Tags: bash, glob

I have the file $HOME/foo/foo.mov

```
if [[ -f $HOME/**/*.mov ]]; then
  echo "file is there" else
  echo "file is not there"
fi
```

echoes "file is not there". whereas,

```
if [ -f $HOME/**/*.mov ]]; then   
  echo "file is there" else
  echo "file is not there"
fi
```

echoes "file there".

Why is the difference between [[ ]] and [ ]?

Comment: relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/confused-about-operators-vs-vs-vs

Comment: shellcheck tells me that [ -f  ] doesn't work with globs. is that true?

Comment: @Bleakley I suspect so, the glob is expanded before commands are executed, so if there is more than one thing that matches the glob you'd have too many arguments to `-f`, if you had `nullglob` enabled you'd have too few if the glob didn't match anything.  Are you trying to tell if there are any files and that's it?

Answer (score 2):

Arguments to the `[` command are subject to pathname expansion; the words used inside `[[ ... ]]` are not.

If you are getting `file is there`, I suspect you have exactly *one* file that matches the pattern. Otherwise, you would have too many arguments for `-f`, or the pattern would be treated as a literal string that does not name an existing file.